# Как запретить автоматическое изменение времени и даты в Linux?

Tags: linux

При изменении даты и времени при включенном интернете - это самое изменённое время заменяется на правильное. Как это запретить?

Мне это нужно,чтобы изменить настройки роутера,который отказывается впускать в админ панель при правильном времени.

Comment: Выключайте ntpd, как — зависит от вашего конкретного линукса

Comment: Linux на Debian.

Comment: systemctl status ntp - выдаёт что сервис не активен.

Comment: если вы **именно так** ставите вопрос: **запретить!**, то я вижу лишь один путь: собрать и запустить программу linux, внеся в неё необходимые изменения. каков вопрос — таков ответ. если вдруг решитесь изменить формулировку, дам подсказку: есть ещё такая популярная программа ntpdate.